# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mention' when trying to read from MySQL with Discord.py

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

Im trying to read from logs stored in a mySQL database and whenever I use this code it always spits out the bottom bit. Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening?

```
# ModLogs
@is_admin()
@client.command()
async def modlogs(self, ctx, logid):
    """
    checks logs via id (temp)
    """
    query = "SELECT * FROM server_logs WHERE logid = %s"
    cursor.execute(query, (logid,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        await ctx.channel.send("Nothing Found")
    else:
        user = client.get_user(int(result["userid"]))
        await ctx.channel.send(user.mention)
```

````
> Ignoring exception in command modlogs: Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 61, in wrapped
>     ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\...\discordbot python\cogs\mod.py", line 30, in
> modlogs
>     await ctx.channel.send(user.mention) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mention'
> 
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line
> 898, in invoke
>     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 550, in invoke
>     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 70, in wrapped
>     raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
> 'mention'
> ```
````

Comment: If you `print(int(result["userid"]))` for some `logid` that would return your id, what do you see?  It may be that your database schema is storing the ids in a type that isn't big enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it a bit easier you can use this:

```
user = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=result["userif"])
```

Hope this helps! :D